# Importing Tweets via Python using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I hope you will notice two thing in this. The first is the `TweepError` in tweepy, and the second is the `TwitterError`  in Twitter. These two errors introduce errors in my application. I installed them many times, but am still facing these two errors. I am using Python 2.6 on Windows 7.

```
>>> import tweepy
>>> dir(tweepy)
['API', 'BasicAuthHandler', 'Cache', 'Cursor', 'DirectMessage', 'FileCache', 'Friendship', 'MemoryCache', 'ModelFactory', 'OAuthHandler', 'SavedSearch', 'SearchResult', 'Status', 'Stream', 'StreamListener', '***TweepError***', 'User', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', 'api', 'auth', 'binder', 'cache', 'cursor', 'debug', 'error', 'models', 'oauth', 'parsers', 'streaming', 'utils']
>>> import twitter
>>> dir(twitter)
['ACCESS_TOKEN_URL', 'AUTHORIZATION_URL', 'Api', 'CHARACTER_LIMIT', 'DEFAULT_CACHE', 'DirectMessage', 'Hashtag', 'List', 'REQUEST_TOKEN_URL', 'SIGNIN_URL', 'Status', 'StringIO', 'Trend', ***'TwitterError'***, 'Url', 'User', '_FileCache', '_FileCacheError', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__version__', 'base64', 'calendar', 'datetime', 'gzip', 'httplib', 'md5', 'oauth', 'os', 'parse_qs', 'parse_qsl', 'rfc822', 'simplejson', 'sys', 'tempfile', 'textwrap', 'time', 'urllib', 'urllib2', 'urlparse']
```

I get this error

```
twitter = Twitter(format="xml")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    twitter = Twitter(format="xml")
NameError: name 'Twitter' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply confused with libraries twitter and python_twitter and tweepy.First read the documentation of library which you want to use and then focus on that library instead looking some other documentation. This error is because you installed twitter and reading documentation of python_twitter

Answer (score 2):

replace:

```
twitter = Twitter(format="xml")
```

with

```
my_twitter = twitter.Twitter(format="xml")
```

Note that I also changed the name of the locally-created instance so that you can continue using `twitter` as name of the module.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do things from [the official Python Twitter Tools page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter/), you should use appropriate import directive `from twitter import *` first. Or read some more about [importing modules in python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) .